# MASM how to make desired function call

Tags: function, masm

I'd like to know, how to do the following.
I have an array, where i have to summ numbers (easy)
but the twist is, that i have to have a function call for it, 
that get's  is params through specific registers. How do i implement that?
In this case, the function needs to get the array (offset) through ESI, and the length of it through ECX.
please educate me
EDIT:
in the meantime i've conjured up this. No idea if this works to as my MASM compliling just broken itself for no reason

```
.data
intarray DWORD 10000h,20000h,30000h,40000h

.code

szummer proc uses esi ecx,
    ptrArray:PTR DWORD, ;points to the array
    szArray: Dword      ;array size
    mov esi, ptrArray ;address of the array
    mov ecx, szArray  ;szize
    mov eax, 0    ;set to 0
AS1:
    add eax, [esi] ;add each int to sum
    add esi, 4  ;point to next int
    loop AS1    ;reapet for array size


ret;
szummer endp

main proc
mov ecx, OFFSET intarray
mov esi, LENGHTOF intarray
INVOKE ArraySum,ecx,esi                     

invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: The `invoke` macro will push the arguments on the stack. If you want to use your own custom calling convention, use the `call` instruction directly.

Answer (score 0):

The MASM directive [INVOKE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/invoke) works only with the [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions#List_of_x86_calling_conventions) C (cdecl), STDCALL, BASIC, FORTRAN and PASCAL. All of these conventions pass the arguments on the stack. Thus, you can't use INVOKE for passing the arguments in registers. You can use the Assembly instruction [CALL](https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_26.html) instead. Your program - slightly modified ;-) - with [MASM32 library](http://www.masm32.com/) included (because of "ExitProcess"):

```
INCLUDE \masm32\include\masm32rt.inc

.DATA

intarray DWORD 10000h,20000h,30000h,40000h

.CODE

szummer proc uses esi ecx
    mov eax, 0      ;set to 0

    AS1:
    add eax, [esi]  ;add each int to sum
    add esi, 4      ;point to next int
    loop AS1        ;reapet for array size

    ret;
szummer endp

main proc
    mov esi, OFFSET intarray
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF intarray
    call szummer

    invoke ExitProcess,0

main ENDP

END main
```